# How to Download my orders from Bricklink

Tags: bricklink

I know you can log in to Bricklink and download my orders as Excel or many other formats, but I am trying to do it programmatically. Does any one know how to do this though Powershell perhaps?

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to use Powershell to download your Bricklink orders, when you can already download them in  XML/CSV?

Comment: Well I want a programmatic way of doing it, so I can download my orders automatically once a month and consolidate them because every now and again bricklink removes the order details from the site. I also want to sync it with an online note taking app so I can keep track of what orders I have revived and what I am waiting for because of where I stay postage can take up to 2 months.

Comment: So I will upload the outstanding orders to a webpage like evernote and add a few custom columns to make it easy for my wife or me to go to a website see hay these orders are outstanding look for the tracking webiste (cause they vary from shipping location) click the link and see where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Bricklink API feature](http://api.bricklink.com/pages/api/welcome.page). I personally have not tried it, but it looks like it should have all the features you need, namely downloading the order list and orders themselves.

Comment: I have seen that , but you have to be a seller to use it . I am only a buyer .